# Same p-value error when using group_by to conduct wilcoxon one sample tests in R

Tags: r, group-by

I am working on a large dataset of offspring sex ratio from +36,000 individuals of over 1,000 species. I want to see if the median sex ratio of each species significantly differs from .5. I am using a one-sample wilcoxon to do this. Here is an example dataset:

```
n<-100
dat<-data.frame(species=rep(LETTERS[1:5],n/5), SR=sample((1:100)/100,n,replace=TRUE))
```

When I run the following code, I get results where all p-values are the same.

```
library(dyplr)
res <- dat %>% group_by(species) %>%
do(w=wilcox.test(dat$SR,mu=.5,alternative=("two.sided"))) %>%
summarize(species,wilcox=w$p.value)
res
#OUTPUT#
# # A tibble: 5 x 2
  species wilcox
  <chr>    <dbl>
1 A        0.465
2 B        0.465
3 C        0.465
4 D        0.465
5 E        0.465
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix this?

Comment: You created SR values ranging from 1 to 100 and then tested to see if the median was significantly different from .5 and they are all very different from .5 (see `tapply(dat$SR, dat$species, median)`). Either test SR/100 or mu=50 or use `runif(n)` to generate sample data between 0 and 1.

Comment: @dcarlson Thank you for the input, I have changed the sample dataset to correct this. The same problem of identical p values emerges no matter what the dataset contains.

Answer (score 0):

The function `do()` is superseded and should not be used anymore. You can do the same within `summarize()` with `across()`.

First you just group by `species` then you use `across()` within `summarize()` to access the values for each group and calculate the wilcoxon test and directly extract its p-value with `$p.value` at the end of the expression.

Mind that I set `exact = FALSE` to prevent the calculation of exact p-values as the sample is to small and it otherwise generates a warning. For your real data you can exclude this statement if your data sample is larger. For more information see this [information](https://data.library.virginia.edu/the-wilcoxon-rank-sum-test/#:%7E:text=The%20impact%20of%20ties%20means,p%2Dvalue%20with%20ties%E2%80%9D.).

```r
n<-100
dat<-data.frame(species=rep(LETTERS[1:5],n/5), SR=sample((1:100)/100,n,replace=TRUE))

library(dplyr)

dat %>% 
  group_by(species) %>%
  summarize(wilcox = across(SR, 
                            ~wilcox.test(., 
                                         mu=.5, 
                                         alternative=("two.sided"),
                                         exact = FALSE)$p.value)$SR)
#> # A tibble: 5 × 2
#>   species wilcox$SR
#>   <chr>       <dbl>
#> 1 A          0.737 
#> 2 B          0.0105
#> 3 C          0.751 
#> 4 D          0.380 
#> 5 E          0.614
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: thank you so much for this response! I've edited my code and it works great. I have run into one more problem though. When I create a tibble from these results by adding res<- to the beginning of that code, the tibble looks perfect when view(res) but if I try to write.csv(res,"res.csv") I get a csv file with 30+ columns of numbers in a seemingly random order with no species names. Any idea why this might be the case?

Comment: I am happy I could help. I have updated my response with a code that works. It looks like that my old code saved the p-values within a list into to column. By adding $SR at the end of the `across()` statement we can access the values directly. After that writing it as .csv should work..